# Swap thumbnail on select .change from PHP Query results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a website to sell picture products either framed, mounted or as prints. I display products in a grid with a thumbnail for the product.

The class of the select option is 'cardid' and class of the thumbnail is 'cardim'. I have 20 of products per page.

Customers can select using a select menu if they want to add it their basket either framed, mounted or just as a print. I'd like to change the thumbnail when they select a different option from the select menu.

How would I make each class unique and how would I handle this in my script.js withour replicating the same code? At the moment if I change any select option all images change.

## Script.js

```
// Event handler for picture selector
$('.cardid').change(function() {
    $(".cardim").attr("src", "images/products/thumb/new-image.jpg");
});
```

This is the code for the thumbnail image.

```
<a class="card_thumb" href="img/products/large/<?php echo $cims[0];?>" title="<?php echo $product['Products_SKU'];?>"><img src="img/products/thumb/<?php echo $cims[0];?>" class="cardim" alt="<?php echo $product['Products_SKU'];?>"></a>
```

And a snippet of code for the select

```
<option value="' . $row['Products_ID'] . '">'. $selector[$key] .'</option>
```

Comment: Why don't you use the product ID as a value for the "id" attribute? and then use `$('#productid').attr(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not unique. Id only unique so use the id like in the a tag

```
<a class="card_thumb" href="img/products/large/<?php echo $cims[0];?>" title="<?php echo $product['Products_SKU'];?>"><img src="img/products/thumb/<?php echo $cims[0];?>" class="cardim" alt="<?php echo $product['Products_SKU'];?>" id="<?php echo $product['Products_ID'];?>"></a>
```

and use the script

```
$('.cardid').change(function() {
     var getId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+getId).attr("src", "images/products/thumb/new-image.jpg");
});
```

Thanks to Jamie Taylor

Comment: Hi Jamie. I understand the logic but keep getting an undefined value. Is this because I have a select for each thumbnail?

Comment: what undefined value u get?

Comment: just 'cardid' what does it need to be changed too? My select is as follows; $rtn .='<select id="picture_options" class="cardid">'; and options as follows; $rtn .= '<option value="' . $row['Products_ID'] . '">'. $selector[$key] .'</option>';

Comment: Yeah. How do I get the value of the select class cardid that changed? At the moment I cannot get it.

Comment: you need to keep the same class name for the select then only we write a code for the element